# Counting by rewritten element

Tags: views, 9

In my view, I'd like to group my row by values.

The initial data look like this.

> [image]

In the field configuration in the view, I rewrite each value like this `{{ field__value |split('-')[2] }}` to get only the last part (CB, VISA...).

How do I group each row by the rewritten value? The idea would be to have this.

> [image]